# SQLAlchemy: Commit not updating all tables

Tags: python, mysql, database, sqlalchemy, orm

So basically I have a code block that gets executed every time a user tries to withdraw money through their account. The problem is that the transaction happens, but rarely the user's balance does not get updated. This has been a recurring issue now. Is this possible? Because I am updating both the tables in a single commit. Shouldn't it roll back if any of the transactions fail? Please let me know if need further clarity. Thank you.

```
if(response['code'] == 200):
    transaction = Transaction(acctitle=current_user.name, accnumber=account_no,
                              amount=amount, transactionid='', status='withdrawn',
                              inv_account_id=current_user.inv_account_id, 
                              transaction_timestamp=str(datetime.now(
                              pytz.timezone('Asia/Karachi'))).split('.')[0],
                              user_id=current_user.id, payment_method=1, 
                              created_at=str(datetime.now(pytz.timezone('Asia/Karachi'))).split('.')[0],
                              branch_code='', bank_code=bank_code, transaction_type_id=9, due_date=0)
                    
    sessiondb.add(transaction)

    account.current_balance = account.current_balance - float(amount)

    try:
        sessiondb.commit()
    except Exception as error:
        sessiondb.rollback()
        logger.exception('Rolling back the changes because of error', error)
        return account

    context = {"envirnment": get_environment(), "mobileno":current_user.mobileno, 
              "name":current_user.name, "amount":float(amount),"bank_code":bank_code,"account_no":account_no,      
              "inv_account_no":current_user.inv_account_id, 'purpose': 'withdraw'}
    data = {"recipient":current_user.email, 
           "subject":"Withdrew Money", "file_name":"withdraw", "context":context}
    notify_user(data)
    return account
else:
    return None
```

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean by "auto-commit"?  If your session is configured with `autocommit=True` then each statement will commit individually.  But the code contains a "manual" commit too.

Comment: I just fixed the title. Ah, my session's auto-commit is set to the default value (which should be false). My auto-commit is enabled for the MySQL database tho.

Comment: What do you see if you `select ENGINE from information_schema.TABLES WHERE TABLE_NAME = 'transaction'` ? (Assuming that `Transaction.__tablename__ == 'transaction'`)

Comment: It shows: InnoDB @GordThompson

Comment: Okay, that's good. If it was 'MyISAM' then that would be bad because the MyISAM engine doesn't support transactions.

Comment: Yeah. That's what I thought but I am not sure why are both the transactions not being considered as a single commit. @GordThompson

Comment: Try checking your code for paths that could result in the `account` object existing but not being attached to the `sessiondb` session.